# What is the best SVG graphics javascript library for IE and other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, svg

I'm working on web application (javascript + jquery) where I need to draw a lot of rectangles and lines between them. As I understand I'm looking for SVG graphics library which will help to create lightweight components (there might be ~300).

The issue is that the application need to support different browsers: Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome. And libraries for Internet Explorer and others are different.

I've already tried Raphael and YUI, but I'm not sure if they are the best variants.

Does anybody have experience with similar questions? Or maybe can advise library which will help to draw in IE and other browsers using one code?

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at [bonsaijs](http://bonsaijs.org/), a lightweight graphics library with an intuitive graphics API and an SVG renderer.
They support IE9+, and all other major browsers.

You can give Bonsai a testdrive with their online editor, [Orbit](http://orbit.bonsaijs.org/). Zero setup involved.

Also they have great [docs](http://docs.bonsaijs.org/) and [examples](http://demos.bonsaijs.org/demos/circles/index.html).

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called "jsPlumb", which can be used as a jQuery or mooTools plugin / extension. You can find a demo at http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html. Documentation is at: http://jsplumb.org/doc/usage.html. Might be useful. The library has a size of 130KB.